# `explorer.exe .` opens System32 directory in Windows 1903

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Windows version 1903 where I am supposed to be able to browse my Linux files by running `explorer.exe .` in Bash, ref https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/.

The result, however, is that the Windows System32 directory is opened instead

I have Ubuntu version 18.04.3. I have tried upgrading the Ubuntu version and, obviously, restarting.

Comment: If should work. Could you please run `pwd` before explorer.exe . to see your current directory?

Comment: I tried from different directories, e.g. `/home/my_user` and `/` - see [Tyler Tinsley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11954688/tyler-tinsley)s answer below and my response.

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse this simple fix, but have you tried to cd into your root directory first? My installation has a nasty tendency to start in System32 depending on how I launch, which will cause this issue.

```
cd /
explorer.exe .
```

If this doesn't take care of the issue, the next thing I would try is to disable and reenable WSL in your optional features- that's taken care of some issues for me in the past.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but they didn't help. Still getting the same result.