# WSL - explorer.exe launches System32 directory

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the exact same problem listed in [`explorer.exe .` opens System32 directory in Windows 1903](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57576576/explorer-exe-opens-system32-directory-in-windows-1903).

When I type the command explorer.exe I get System32 only, not my current file location.

[image]

How do I get my current location correct?

Comment: Possible solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1338991/how-to-open-windows-explorer-from-current-working-directory-of-wsl-shell)

Comment: @vulpxn That's the exact same as the question I linked above, just a different context...Please read the solution and compare it. **It's the same.**

Comment: I do not see where that post is linked from the question you referenced, but regardless,*none* of the solutions posted at the other link worked? I was just able to verify them all working. If you navigate to `\\wsl$` in the explorer navigation bar are you able to access it? I only have a single distro installed on my machine so granted I am not sure if this behaves different with multiple OS present.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sh
$ explorer.exe $(wslpath -w $(pwd))
# or,
$ alias explorer='explorer.exe $(wslpath -w $(pwd))'
```

Comment: It says "Invalid argument".

Comment: Then it must be something specific with your install. For reference I am on Windows 1909 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: I am on Version 1809 with Ubuntu 18.04. Not much different.

Comment: If you enter `\\wsl$` in your regular explorer navigation bar it should take you to a folder inside of which is a folder called `Ubuntu`, from there you can traverse as you wish. I'd try that and if that does not work look at either filing an issue somewhere or doing a fresh install.

Comment: Uninstalling WSL entirely and re-installing it. There's a discussion [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2703) on how to go about it